# "Bernstein version" of McDiarmid?

Tags: inequality, reference-request, concentration-of-measure

I have seen used in a paper the following variant of McDiarmid's inequality, referred to as a "Bernstein-type variant":

> **Theorem.** Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, and $X_1,\dots, X_n$ be independent random variables, and let, for $1\leq i\leq n$,
> $$
> v_i^2 := \max_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} \mathbb{E}[ (f(x_1,\dots, x_{i-1}, X_i, x_{i+1}, \dots, x_n) - \mathbb{E}[f(x_1,\dots, x_{i-1}, X_i, x_{i+1}, \dots, x_n)])^2],
> $$
> and
> $$
> B := \max_{1\leq i\leq n}\max_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} |f(x) - \mathbb{E}[f(x_1,\dots, x_{i-1}, X_i, x_{i+1}, \dots, x_n)]|
> $$
> Then, for all $t>0$, we have
> $$
> \mathbb{P}\{ |f(X)-\mathbb{E}[f(X)]| \geq t \} \leq 2\exp\left({-\frac{t^2}{2\sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2 + \frac{t}{3}B}}\right)
> $$

The reference given is [this note by Y. Ying](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/Y.Ying/McDiarmid.pdf) (PDF), and I couldn't find any other source.

In particular, this doesn't seem to be mentioned, or immediately follow from any of the results in the Boucheron–Lugosi–Massart *Concentration Inequalities* book (it looks related to Theorems 6.16, 8.6, and 12.2, but they seem either weaker or incomparable (?)).

> Is there a textbook or peer-reviewed reference for the statement above (or an analogous one, with maybe different constants)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague pointed to me that this is described in Eq. (8.5) of [1] (the result then follows from their Theorem 8.2 combined with this), and shown in Problem 8.14 in that book.

It is also in the original paper by McDiarmid [2], as Theorem 3.8.

> [1] Dubhashi, Devdatt P.; Panconesi, Alessandro. *Concentration of measure for the analysis of randomized algorithms.* Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 2009. xvi+196 pp. ISBN: 978-0-521-88427-3

> [2] McDiarmid, Colin. *Concentration. Probabilistic methods for algorithmic discrete mathematics*, 195--248, Algorithms Combin., 16, Springer, Berlin, 1998.